# can someone help with this question with capacitors

Tags: power-engineering, electrical

[image: pic]

Please I need help solving this one, the book is Thomas Floyd 3rd edition Electric circuit fundamentals.
The final answer is supposed to be \$ \text{0.0052 } \mu F\$

The ac source frequency \$f=141471 \text{ Hz}\$, \$X_{C_2}= \text{562 }\Omega\$, and \$X_{C_{23}} = \text{321 }\Omega\$.

---

my steps are as follow :

1. i find frequency of the ac source from reactance 3 , then
2. i find Xc2 , after that i find current going through C2
3. i find equ capacitance of 2 and 3 and their equivalent reactance
4. then i find drop voltage on the equ reactance
5. find reactance of C1
6. then the calue of C1 capacitance

Comment: We don't expect every post to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get read and upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your post to improve it. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages. If English is not your first language then add this into your user profile so we'll understand.

Comment: i am new to this site so forgive me . 
now 
the ac source frequency f=141471 Hz
Xc2=562 ohm 
Xc23=321 
this current is in rms 

can someone solve this pls ?

Comment: So far, so good. But you also know the current in C3; can that tell you anything?

Comment: i can use the current through C3 to find voltage drop in C3 which is equal to C2 and then we find the drop for C1 am i right till now ?

Comment: thx guys i made mistake only because i thought that the vltage drop in C3 &C2 is the same as the source that was my mistake

Comment: Since we know both the value and current in \$C_3\$ we know the voltage.  from \$X_c\$ this  gives us the frequency and this the current in \$C_2\$ Kirchoff's current law gives us the current in \$C_1\$ and hence its value.  Where are you having difficulties? Not *Unclear what you are asking* but  does not show much effort.

Answer (score 4):

1. freq= 141474 Hz
2. Xc2=562
3. V3=V2=750 * 4 mA = 3 volt
4. V1= 5-3 = 2 volts
5. find Ic2=3/562 = 5.3 mA
6. total current = 5.3 + 4 = 9.3 mA
7. Xc1 = 2/9.3 mA = 215 ohm
8. then we use the formula C1=1/2*pi*f*Xc1= 0.0052 microfarad

Comment: Please check your post using the preview before submitting. There are buttons on the editor toolbar to assist you with creating proper lists. (I've fixed the list for you.) They don't help you with capitalisation and punctuation. You have to do that yourself.